# Rails Join in Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, models, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to use a belongs_to relationship inside a has_many as below.

In words: I want unique Reports that belong to a DownloadSchedule while being constrained by the client_id.

```
class DownloadSchedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :custom_data

  belongs_to :client

  has_many :report_column_schedule_links
  has_many :reports, -> { uniq where("report_column_schedule_links.client_id = ?", self.client.id) }, :through => :report_column_schedule_links
end
```

The error thrown is

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'report_column_schedule_links.client_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `reports`.* FROM `reports`  WHERE (report_column_schedule_links.client_id = 1)
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'report_column_schedule_links.client_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `reports`.* FROM `reports`  WHERE (report_column_schedule_links.client_id = 1)
```

Is this possible with a has_many or do I have to write a custom join? I'm using Rails 4.

[Update]
The structure for report_column_schedule_links is below.

```
create_table :report_column_schedule_links do |t|
  t.integer :report_id
  t.integer :report_column_id
  t.integer :client_id
  t.integer :schedule_id
  t.integer :download_schedule_id

  t.timestamps
end
```

You'll notice the MySQL error is on the statement

```
SELECT `reports`.* FROM `reports`  WHERE (report_column_schedule_links.client_id = 1)
```

This statement isn't performing the join on the has_many.

Thanks,
Justin

Comment: what is the name of the association corresponding to 'report_column_schedule_links', associations? does table associated with it has client_id column?

Comment: What is the structure of the report_column_schedule_links table?